# Mesh / unwrapping a face

Tags: uv

So i can select desired faces and unwrap. Good.
But if i select a face without holding shift my unwrapped part disapears.

How do i keep the selected faces as the parts i want to use and have that as my mesh?
So for example if i only want to add an image to the selected faces.

So i am trying to save the one on the left.[image]

Comment: When assigning an image (material)  to a group of faces it assigns based on which faces are selected on your mesh, not what is selected in the UV Image Editor.

Comment: I do not want to assign an image just yet. I want the front of the number plate to be unwrapped. so i dont have to select the faces every time i want to add an image. I want to select the faces and then save the selection?

Comment: One useful trick is that you can select faces based on Material, so if you select your numberplate faces and assign a Numberplate material to them, then you can come back in later and from the Material picker just press Select and those faces will be selected again.Not sure if that suits.

Comment: That works perfectly thank you so much.